# Не работает скролл в ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

В моем ListView с кнопками по непонятной мне причине, не хочет работать скролл
Вот Listview

```
<ListView  RelativePanel.Below="Sep" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionMode="Single" 
                     SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="Black" Background="{x:Null}" >
                            <ListViewItem Name="Web" ManipulationMode="TranslateX"
                  ManipulationCompleted="SplitViewPane_ManipulationCompleted">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Name="im2" Source="Resource/Site.png" Height="26" Width="26" />
                                    <TextBlock Name="tx2" FontSize="16" Margin="15,0,0,0">Панель 2</TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ListViewItem>
                            <ListViewItem Visibility="Collapsed" Name="News" ManipulationMode="TranslateX"
                  ManipulationCompleted="SplitViewPane_ManipulationCompleted">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Name="im3" Source="Resource/News.png" Height="26" Width="26" />
                                    <TextBlock Name="tx3" FontSize="16" Margin="15,0,0,0">Панель 3</TextBlock>
                               </StackPanel> </ListViewItem> </ListView>
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть беда? (подозреваю, что это из за кнопок)

**UPD**
Если тяну за часть где нет кнопок, скролл работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если за кнопки то игнорирует
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "не хочет работать скролл"? Не отображаются полосы прокрутки? Тогда какие? Или полоса прокрутки отображается, но ее перемещение не дает результатов? Или колесиком не прокручивается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предполагаю, что `ListView` находится в `StackPanel` или в строке грида с `Height="auto"`. Поместите его в строку грида с размером `Height="*"`.

UPD: Вот такой каркас должен быть.

```
<ListView
    ItemTemplate="ListViewWithButtonsItemTemplate"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"/>

<DataTemplate
    x:Name="ListViewWithButtonsItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <FontIcon 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Glyph="{Binding Image}"/>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Заметил, что скролл не работает если тянуть за кнопки, а если таскать за части где нет кнопок скролл дает о себе знать

Comment: Покажите скрин как все выглядит.

Comment: приложения или кода?

Comment: Добавил скриншоты

Comment: Думаю проблема в распространении события. Кнопки перехватывают его и не пускают дальше. Как с этим бороться в данном случае - хз. Могу лишь посоветовать сделать кнопки по-человечески, через ItemTemplate, тогда всё точно будет работать нормально.

Comment: как по-человечески?)

Comment: Если пунктов больше 5, то в коде сделать `List<MenuItem>`, в котором `MenuItem` это класс, состоящий из 3-х свойств:
 `string` "Значок",
 `string` "Название кнопки",
 `string` "Адрес, куда должна вести кнопка". 
Привязать этот `List<MenuItem>` к `ListView` в качестве `ItemsSource` и добавить `ItemTemplate`, в котором уже задать верстку кнопки. В коде перехватывать событие `SelectionChanged` списка и делать то, что указано в свойстве "Адрес" кнопки.

Comment: У вас случайно нет примера кода такого решения?

Comment: Примера класса? В чем сложность?

Comment: Пример xaml просто мне код текстом как то туго воспринимается...

Comment: Обновил ответ, дописал пример.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что не хватает контрола `ScrollViewer` вокруг листа

```
<ScrollViewer>
<ListView  RelativePanel.Below="Sep" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionMode="Single" 
                     SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="Black" Background="{x:Null}" >
                            <ListViewItem Name="Web" ManipulationMode="TranslateX"
                  ManipulationCompleted="SplitViewPane_ManipulationCompleted">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Name="im2" Source="Resource/Site.png" Height="26" Width="26" />
                                    <TextBlock Name="tx2" FontSize="16" Margin="15,0,0,0">Панель 2</TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ListViewItem>
                            <ListViewItem Visibility="Collapsed" Name="News" ManipulationMode="TranslateX"
                  ManipulationCompleted="SplitViewPane_ManipulationCompleted">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Name="im3" Source="Resource/News.png" Height="26" Width="26" />
                                    <TextBlock Name="tx3" FontSize="16" Margin="15,0,0,0">Панель 3</TextBlock>
                               </StackPanel> </ListViewItem> </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Лист сам по себе не содержит в себе `ScrollViewer`

Comment: Еще как содержит. Как тогда виртуализация списков работает?)